# Issues with exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to build an array of functions. I have a folder full of modules where each module has a function run and the following line

```
 exports.run = run;
 var run = function(db){
   // Run some code
 }
```

I then have a file I call in node which does the following:

```
require("fs").readdirSync("./channels").forEach(function(file) {
  var func = require("./channels/" + file);
  channels.push(func);
  console.log("Adding " + file);
  console.log(channels);
});
```

The function above successfully adds in each file with type undefined. I'm unable to run the functions because of this. How can I successfully build this array of functions?

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code doesn't work as you expect it to, is [variable hoisting in JavaScript](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2013/12/09/javascript-variable-hoisting).

```
var run = function(db){
    // Run some code
}

exports.run = run;
```

If you don't want to push your `exports` line to the bottom of your function, then you'll have to declare `run` as a stand-alone function, rather than assigning it to a variable.

```
exports.run = run;

function run(db){
    // Run some code
}
```